# Accessing elements of a multi-dimensional array obtained from excel file

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to extract cells from an excel file into a multi-dimensional array in C#. I have the following code snippet:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(this.pathToFile);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;


Object[,] dataArray;

dataArray = (System.Object[,])xlRange.Value2;

Console.WriteLine(dataArray.GetLength(0));
Console.WriteLine(dataArray.GetLength(1));
Console.WriteLine(dataArray[0,0]); //As a test
```

The code works up until the last line, where it throws an IndexOutOfRange Exception. The two lines above that line print properly with:

```
2
117
"IndexOutOFRangeException"
```

Shouldn't something exist at the 0,0 position in the array if its lengths are 2 and 117, respectively? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Oddly, I have found some things in C# to be 1-based. You might try populating a range with some data and if [1,1] doesn't return the first cell's content.

Comment: I would say that it's Excel itself that's 1-based, so this could definitely be an artifact of that @user2320861

Comment: The value would be a variant.  Are you sure it's printable?

Comment: What do `dataArray.GetLowerBound(0)`, `dataArray.GetLowerBound(1)`, `dataArray.GetUpperBound(0)` and `dataArray.GetUpperBound(1)` return, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

As some comments said, Excel types in C# are 1-based.

In your code to open the first worksheet you wrote

```
// index is 1
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
```

The index of the first sheet in your workbook is 1, not 0.

When you want to get the data from your dataArray you should start from [1,1]

```
// will write to top left value from your worksheet
Console.WriteLine(dataArray[1, 1]);
```

I think they used 1-based array because the worksheets are named "Sheet1" "Sheet2" by default, and rows starts from 1, you don't have A0.

[image: excel]

It would seems logical for any normal person but for us developper used to 0-based array it looks strange.